# fopen failing in Kernel Command but not in controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using fopen to generate a csv file. The function works as expected in a test controller but when I move to a Console/Commands file, it fails with 'failed to open stream: No such file or directory'.

This is the fopen line;

```
$fp = fopen('dataFiles/dataFile_'.date('Ymd').'.csv', 'w');
```

I have tried to change the url declaration to;

```
$fp = fopen('/dataFiles/dataFile_'.date('Ymd').'.csv', 'w');
```

No dice. The dataFiles folder is in my projects public dir.

What could be the issue here?

This is a 5.3 project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use the `public_path()` to specify the public folder location. otherwise the file location is taken from the existing folder. in your case it is checking if the is file existing in Console folder, in your second example it is taking the file path from the project root.

```
$fp = fopen(public_path('dataFiles/dataFile_'.date('Ymd').'.csv', 'w'));
```

I have one suggestion for you. if you are not planning to make this files public you should put them in the storage folder. That's the place for these kind of files

[Path helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-app-path)

Comment: Excellent.  Thought it was path related.  Also, +1 for the storage suggestion.  Thanks!